# IN statement inconsistency with PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key

So I have a simple table called temp that can be created by:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (value int, id int not null primary key);
INSERT INTO temp
VALUES(0,1),
      (0,2),
      (0,3),
      (0,4),
      (1,5),
      (1,6),
      (1,7),
      (1,8);
```

I have a second table temp2 that can be created by:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (value int, id int);
INSERT INTO temp
VALUES(0,1),
      (0,2),
      (0,3),
      (0,4),
      (1,5),
      (1,6),
      (1,7),
      (1,8);
```

The only difference between temp and temp2 is that the id field is the primary key in temp, and temp2 has no primary key.  I'm not sure how, but I am getting differing results with the following query:

```
select * from temp
where id in (
    select id
    from (
        select id, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by value order by value) rownum
        from temp
    ) s1
    where rownum = 1
)
```

This is the result for temp:

```
value       id
----------- -----------
0           1
0           2
0           3
0           4
1           5
1           6
1           7
1           8
```

and this is what I get when temp is replaced by temp2 (*THE CORRECT RESULT*):

```
value       id
----------- -----------
0           1
1           5
```

When running the inner-most query (s1), the expected results are retrieved:

```
id          rownum
----------- --------------------
1           1
2           2
3           3
4           4
5           1
6           2
7           3
8           4
```

When just running the `in` statement query on both, I also get the expected result:

```
id
-----------
1
5
```

I cannot figure out what the reason for this could possibly be.  Is this a bug?

Notes: temp2 was created with a simple `select * into temp2 from temp`.  I am running SQL Server 2008.  My apologies if this is a known glitch.  It is difficult to search for this since it requires an `in` statement.  An "equivalent" query that uses a join **does** produce the correct results on both tables.

Edit: dbfiddle showing the differences:
[Unexpected Results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fee503ff9036c105c0a8c7bdb11b72d) 
[Expected Results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=46867d90b2abab037a1468d9519968ea)

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, the query works as you intend: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=46867d90b2abab037a1468d9519968ea). Are we missing something here?

Comment: @Larnu Here it is: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fee503ff9036c105c0a8c7bdb11b72d

Comment: Put those 2 dbfiddles (the actual code) in the question, @Jason. They are **very** important to the question.

Comment: Read the manual for how ROW_NUMBER() works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't specifically answer your question, but changing the `ORDER BY` fixes the problem. `partition by value order by value` doesn't really make sense, and it looks like the problem is "fooling" SQL Server; as you're partitioning the rows by the same value you're ordering by, every row is "row number 1" as they could all be at the start. Don't forget, a table is an unordered heap; *even* when it has a Primary Key (clustered or not).

If you change your `ORDER BY` to `id` instead the problem goes away.

```
SELECT *
FROM temp2 t2
WHERE t2.id IN (SELECT s1.id
                FROM (SELECT sq.id,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sq.value ORDER BY sq.id) AS rownum
                      FROM temp2 sq) s1
                WHERE s1.rownum = 1);
```

In fact, changing the `ORDER BY` clause to anything else fixes the problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM temp2 t2
WHERE t2.id IN (SELECT s1.id
                FROM (SELECT sq.id,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sq.value ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
                      FROM temp2 sq) s1
                WHERE s1.rownum = 1);
```

So the problem is that your are using the same expression (column) for both your `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clause; meaning that any of those rows could be row number 1, and none of them; thus all are returned. It doesn't make sense for both to be the same, so they should be different.

Still, this problem does persist in SQL Server 2017 (and I suspect 2019) so you *might* want to raise a support ticket with them anyway (but as you're using 2008 don't expect it to get fixed, as your support is about to end).

*As comments can be deleted without notice I wanted to add @scsimon's comment and my response:*

> scsimon: Interesting. Changing `rownum = 2` gives expected results without changing `order by`. I think it's a bug.
>
> Larnu: I agree at @scsimon. I suspect that changing the `WHERE` to `s1.rownum = 2` effectively forces the data engine to actually determine the values of `rownum`, rather than assume every row is "equal"; as if that were the case none would be returned.
>   Even so, changing the `WHERE` to `s1.rownum = 2` is still resigning to "return a random row", if the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses are the same

Comment: Interesting. Changing rownum = 2 gives expected results without changing `order by`. I think it's a bug.

Comment: I agree at @scsimon. I suspect that changing the `WHERE` to `s1.rownum = 2` effectively forces the data engine to actually determine the values of `rownum`, rather than *assume* every row is "equal"; as if that were the case none would be returned.

Comment: @Larnu you say "persist" - is it a documented known issue?

Comment: Even so, change the `WHERE` to `s1.rownum = 2` is still resigning to "return a random row", if the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses are the same

Comment: What I mean is that the issue still happens in SQL Server 2017 @GeorgeMenoutis. The DB fiddl in the comments under the question shows this, and I received the same behaviour during own tests when writing this answer (as I am using 2017). I haven't spun up my 2019 container to check however.

Comment: I can confirm this happening on 2012 and 2017, too.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. There are really quite a large number of criteria that must be met to get this behavior. For one, I normally try to avoid this use of `in` for performance reasons. A simple `join` was used to get the desired results, but those results really had a colleague and me very confused. The`rownum = 2` work around is also interesting (and puzzling) as well.